# Two brown-haired people have two children, P and Q. P has blond hair. Q has brown hair. What is the probability that Q is heterozygous?

Tags: genetics, homework, statistics

Two brown-haired people have two children, P and Q. P has blond hair. We therefore believe that each parent is heterozygous and that blond hair is a recessive trait.
Q has brown hair. What is the probability that Q is heterozygous?

My answer:  2/3.  There are four possibilities Bb, bB, BB,and bb. Before observing the color of Q's hair, we assign equal chance to each.  We eliminate bb as a possibility.  The chance that it is bB or Bb and not BB is 2/3.

A Biology PhD disagrees with me and says that the probability is 1/2. Who is right?

Comment: now ask that PhD to solve the Monte hall problem.

Comment: @Memming that's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

Comment: I am familiar with the Monty Hall problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Assumptions: *Blonde* hair is *Homozygous Recessive* and that the traits are strictly Mendelian.**

The parental generation must be both heterozygotes as at least one child is Blonde (bb). So your cross is **Bb** x **Bb**.

Your square is going to look like this:

```
           _B_            _b_

_B_         BB           Bb



_b_         bB           bb
```

So of the question is:

> What is the probability that Q is heterozygous?

The PhD is **INCORRECT**. They probably just made a simple Punnet Square in their head and forgot the caveat that you have to exclude "**bb**" because Q is *not* Blonde. The possible allele combinations for **non-Blonde** offspring from a Heterozygotic cross are only **BB, bB, Bb**.

Therefor the probability that **Q** is *Heterozygous* is indeed 2/3 (**bB, Bb**).

It's not uncommon for PhD students - who are often deep into their own research - to gloss over details and possibly give incorrect answers because the information hasn't been relevant to them for years (most traits *aren't* Mendelian, strictly recessive or dominant, and rarely involve a single allele), so give them some slack unless they were being a jerk about it. =)

Comment: Just to complete the answer, this essentially is an application of [Bayes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

Comment: I worked it out that way, too.  But adding another layer of mathematics isn't going to prove anything to someone who disagrees with the simple way of seeing things.

Comment: Then you have one more argument: this was probably a high school homework, so it has to use what kids learn about Mendelian heredity, not something deeper and more elaborate.